# java.lang.NullPointerException: The mapper function returned a null value. при установке моего приложения

Tags: java, android, android-studio

У меня есть приложение календаря с заметками. Сначала для его тестирования на реальном устройстве, я всегда генерировал debug-версию apk. А потом я решил протестировать приложение на устройствах друзей, и для этого я сгенерировал release-версию моего apk c цифровой подписью. Всё было нормально, но после некоторых изменений в манифесте apk перестал устанавливаться (при установке выдаёт "Приложение не установлено. Возможно, пакет повреждён") В logcat была вот такая ошибка: java.lang.NullPointerException: The mapper function returned a null value. В чём у меня проблема, и как её устранить? Подойдут любые варианты. Заранее спасибо.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.masterok.calendar">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <application

        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ikon_for_calendar_1"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Calendar"
        android:allowBackup="false">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"

            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            tools:ignore="ExtraText"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".EditActivity"
            android:exported="false"

            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.EditTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Notes"
            android:exported="true"

            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-5488979700425931~2033858825" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle(:app):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.masterok.calendar"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled=true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary=true
        minSdkVersion 21
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        targetSdkVersion 31
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

build.gradle(Calendar):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {

        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'

        
    }

}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда я чуть-чуть повозился с этой проблемой, то понял, в чём проблема: в файле `build.gradle(:app)`, а именно в конфигурации подписи apk файла. По умолчанию она была `debug`, а само приложение было `release`. Проблема решилась при изменении конфигурации подписи на `release`, а именно, добавлением в `build.gradle(:app)`следующих строчек:

```
signingConfigs {
        release {

        }
    }
```

Я думаю, этот ответ поможет тем, у кого такая же проблема.